# All of a sudden paperclip won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

> Photo Could not run the `identify` command. Please install
>   ImageMagick.

Paperclip have been working fine in development but suddenly I can't upload a Photo..
Don't have imagemagic installed, but it worked earlier. Does anyone have a clue?

This is my console error:

```
 Setting Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "14"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/ubuntu_wallpaper_by_hyarmenadan-d54zgpm20130926-11024-9efnnx.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/ubuntu_wallpaper_by_hyarmenadan-d54zgpm20130926-11024-9efnnx.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/ubuntu_wallpaper_by_hyarmenadan-d54zgpm20130926-11024-9efnnx.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paperclip uses ImageMagick, so you had it before when you could use paperclip.

ImageMagick is a dependency for a lot of softwares, so maybe it was installed by an other package, and was then removed when using something like `apt-get autoremove`.

Any way, you have to install ImageMagick for paperclip to be able to use its `identify` and `convert` binaries :

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

The `identify` binary is used to retrieve size for images (that is : your original image, to store its size and maybe validates it).

The `convert` binary is used to change an image, like resizing it or changing format (jpg, png, etc) ... among many transformations possible. See its man page for full details.

Comment: Aha okey, will look in my gemdirectory. Don't have the imageMagick gem in my gemfile. What does the identify method do?

Comment: ImageMagick is not a gem, it's a system package. `apt-get install imagemagick` ?